# Where to position 'await' statement in Hardhat tests?

Tags: hardhat, testing, async

According to [Hardhat Tutorial](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/testing-contracts), while writing tests, some cases are written like

```
expect(await hardhatToken.totalSupply()).to.equal(ownerBalance);
```

while others are written

```
await expect(hardhatToken.transfer(addr1.address, 50)).to.changeTokenBalances(hardhatToken, [owner, addr1], [-50, 50]);
```

What is the rule behind positioning `await` statement in tests? When should it go before and when inside of `expect()` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `await` **inside** `expect` when you want to use pre-fetched exact result for comparison.

You should use `await` **outside** `expect` when you want chai matchers to fetch the result in "the functions way".

1st example is about comparing two numbers, and its properly used inside the `expect`

2nd example requires chai matchers to do some additional checks, like fetching balance before and after, so the function cannot be pre-fetched and needs to be invoked by the matcher.

`await` **outside** is commonly used to test for reverts, because using it straight away would throw an exception, but the matcher will protect from that and check the result of the exception